# How to Save boolean properly on Playerprefs?

Tags: unity

I want to make a shop system if I buy the items, the items will be saved on Playerprefs, no need to buy again when I restart or re-open the game, for that I already make it to `setInt` but I don't know when I call `getInt`. I tried to call it in the `start method` with a new `int index` but it doesn't work.
This my script

for store the itemsType

```
[System.Serializable]
public class m_ShopItem 
{
    public Sprite theIcon;
    public int price;
    public bool isBuyed=false;
}
```

Then I make it list

```
public List<m_ShopItem> ShopItemsList = new List<m_ShopItem>();
 [SerializeField] GameObject ShopPanel;
    [SerializeField] Transform theContent;
    GameObject g;
    Button buyBtn;
    public GameObject itemTemplate;

void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
            Instance = this;
        else
            Destroy(gameObject);

        for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemsList.Count; i++)
        {
            // Create a different PlayerPrefs for each Item in the Shop.
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed" + i, ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ShopItemsList.Count; i++)
        {

             g = Instantiate(itemTemplate, theContent);
            g.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = ShopItemsList[i].theIcon;
            g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = ShopItemsList[i].price.ToString();
            buyBtn = g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed" + i) == 1 ? true : false;
            if (ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed)
            {
                DisableBuyButton();
            }
            buyBtn.AddEventListener(i, OnShopItemBtnClicked);
            Debug.Log(ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed);
        }
    }
    void OnShopItemBtnClicked(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (m_shopManager.Instance.HasEnoughCoins(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].price))
        {
            m_shopManager.Instance.UseCoins(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].price);
            //purchase Item
            ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed = true;
            PPlayerPrefs.SetInt("isBuyed" + itemIndex, ShopItemsList[itemIndex].isBuyed ? 1 : 0);

            //disable the button
            buyBtn = theContent.GetChild(itemIndex).GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            DisableBuyButton();

            //add avatar
            m_Profile.Instance.AddBallType(ShopItemsList[itemIndex].theIcon);
        }
        else
        {
            //NoCoinsAnim.SetTrigger("NoCoins");
            Debug.Log("You don't have enough coins!!");
        }
    }

    void DisableBuyButton()
    {
        buyBtn.interactable = false;
        buyBtn.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = "PURCHASED";
    }
```

but the result is the same I have to rebuy when going to the main menu or restart the game.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my script?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead? Are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: @Philipp that's mean when I call `ShopItemsList[i].isBuyed = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isBuyed") == 1 ? true : false;` change the `i` to `ItemIndex` that is same doesn't work to save the boolean to PlayerPrefs

also there is no error on it

Comment: @Philipp so basically I want to save boolean when I buy an item to playerprefs then when I reload the scene or restart the game the item I bought is available to equip

Comment: It looks like you're trying to save and load the purchased state of multiple different items to a single shared 1 or 0... how exactly do you plan for this to work?

Comment: @DMGregory I already update the script so that's will save on multiple initial PLayerPrefs not single but the problem same the bool not save in PlayerPrefs.